# Do I add +1 to memory allocation in function after removing newline character in main?

Tags: c, function, malloc, strlen

If I prompt user to give filename as input, then check for and remove newline character do I still have to add `+1` to `strlen(filename)` when allocating memory i function, because of using strlen and the fact that it counts characters without the last character?

Or there's no need for that since I removed it in `main()`?

I've read that not adding +1 can allocate to little memory for string and cause problems, but I read contradictory things on the matter and would appreciate some clarification.

```
double** wczytaj_macierz (char* filename, int x, int y)
{
  char    *file = malloc(strlen(filename) + 1);

  sprintf(file, "%s", filename);
  FILE *fin = fopen (file, "r");



...
rest of the code
...

int main(void)
   char    filename[BUFSIZ];
{
  printf("\nPlease enter filename, max %d characters.\n", sizeof(filename));
  if (fgets(filename, sizeof(filename), stdin) != NULL)
  {
    if ((p = strchr(filename, '\n')) != NULL) 
    {
      *p = '\0';
    }
  }
wczytaj_macierz (filename, x, y);
```

Comment: If you are going to copy the string pointed to by the pointer filename you shall write char    *file = malloc(strlen(filename) + 1);

Comment: It's not clear whether you're asking about if you took the string length _before_ removing the newline or not.  You never call the function `wczytaj_macierz`, so it's unclear what the purpose there is.  Basically, this is confusing.  Just remember this: If you "remove" a character by null-terminating your string, then subsequent calls to `strlen` will return the new length of the string.  If you need to allocate memory for a string, it MUST be sufficient to store the string AND its null-terminator.  So if you plan to use null-terminated strings then you must add 1 to whatever the length is.

Comment: Needs a [mcve].  But also keep in mind that the string returned by `fgets` is not guaranteed to end with a newline, so you had better handle the length correctly whether it is there or not.

Comment: I tried to make it minimal, as guy in previous post told the exact same thing, when I copied entire code (it wasn't a long program then), so I tried to give only the most important pieces for the problem at hand,, guess too little.
Sorry @paddy, I edited my post and added function call, but I just call the function giving arguments, first is filename, other two are matrix dimensions, also given by the user, by using scanf in main.
But I think you answered my question, if I understand correctly I still have to add one character.

Comment: Well, I suppose so...  But who really knows?!  In your example, all you do is just allocate memory for no reason.  You never copy a string into it, and it's not clear if you _need_ to copy the file name at all.  What are you going to do with it?  The function returns a `double**`.  So unless you're doing some crazy type punning to return this dynamically-allocated string inside an array of `double` arrays, or re-using the `filename` buffer for something else, then what is the point?  The file name is already contained in the parameter passed in.  It looks to me like you don't need to copy it.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right, I left out important part. I added `sprintf()` I use in function to send filename to string `file`, which I then use to open the file. My main issue is that in both cases (with or without 1) code works, but I wonder if I'm getting lucky with memory allocation and with different names it might break or not. I should've prepared this thread better, sorry for wasting your time and mistakes.

Comment: All right, thanks for editing.  Now you're just leaking memory.  Why not `fopen (filename, "r");` in the first place?  And make the parameter `const char*` instead, so its purpose is obvious.

Comment: Thank you, now I see sprintf() is pointless. I tried with just `fopen` before and had some problem so I tried `sprintf()`. Now I think I was making some typos and didn't notice in the heat of the battle, switched to worse solution and stuck with it. I removed sprintf() and it works fine. Thanks for the help @paddy.

Comment: _Side note:_ In `wczytaj_macierz`, you can eliminate `malloc` and `file` and _just_ do: `FILE *fin = fopen(filename,"r");` [as `fopen` does _not_ alter its argument].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you allocate memory for a string, you must *always* allocate one more byte than the length of the string.  That extra byte is for the terminating `'\0'` character.

If you have a string that happens to end in a newline `\n` character, and you strip that character off, you will obviously make the string one character shorter, and this means you will need one less byte of memory to store it.  But storing it will still require space for the `\0`, as always.

As an example:

```
char string[] = "test\n";
int stringlen = strlen(string);            // length = 5
char *copy1 = malloc(stringlen + 1);       // allocates 6 bytes
strcpy(copy1, string);                     // this works
char *p = strchr(string, '\n');            // find the \n
if(p != NULL) *p = '\0';                   // strip it off
printf("string is now: \"%s\"\n", string);
stringlen = strlen(string);                // length = 4
char *copy2 = malloc(stringlen + 1);       // allocates 5 bytes
strcpy(copy2, string);                     // this works also
```

Now, *if* you wrote the code like this:

```
char string[] = "test\n";
int stringlen = strlen(string);
char *p = strchr(string, '\n');
if(p != NULL) *p = '\0';
printf("string is now: \"%s\"\n", string);
char *copy = malloc(stringlen);           // don't have to add 1,
                                          // since I just stripped off \n
strcpy(copy, string);
```

it looks like you can get away with not adding the `+ 1`.  But any time you have to add a comment to explain some code that's not there, and especially if the comment you have to write is *longer* than the code it replaces, it's usually a sign that you've gotten too clever, that you ought to just leave the code in.  And, indeed, even though it might seem to work at first, writing the code this way would be pretty dangerous, because if you ever end up with a string that doesn't end in `\n`, meaning that there's nothing to strip off, the code will stop working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answers your question :?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char filename[10];

    printf("\nPlease enter filename, max %d characters.\n", sizeof(filename));
    if (fgets(filename, sizeof(filename), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n", filename, strlen(filename));
    if (filename[strlen(filename) - 1] == '\n')
    {
        filename[strlen(filename) - 1] = '\0'; // Here lies \n
    }
    printf("%s %d\n", filename, strlen(filename));
    }

    // If filename was "file\n\0", filename[strlen(filename) - 1] == '\n'
    // Now with filename[strlen(filename) - 1] = '\0'
    // filename is "file\0\0" that is "file\0".
    // strlen("file\n") == 5
    // strlen("file") = 4

    // strlen(filename) was 5 and now it is 4

    

    return 0;
}
```